# Can't set max-width to a row

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a website I made in wordpress with live composer. Here is a link http://webr.hol.es/
I want to make the parallax image full width and I tried to change custom css/add new plugins but It didn't work.. I tried to find an answer on stackoverflow/wordpress forum/live composer website but everything I found didn't work.. Maybe you know a plugin or how to edit that damn code in order to make it full width
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change line 252 in your style.css - set `padding` to `15px`, so your page wrapper has 100% width of the body (you need to count in 15px, because `row` has -15px on sides, also in other class there is padding-top/bottom set to 15px, so you can set it to all sides and it will work)

```
.page .page-wrap .content-wrapper,
.single .page-wrap .content-wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
}
```